# Are RPM change logs about the RPM or the software it contains?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I've been playing with RPMs recently and been using the `%changelog` section. When there is a software update to apply, I've update the version and added what changes I've made to the change log section. In my attempts to continue my understanding of the RPM SPEC file, I stumbled upon the [Fedora Project's RPM Package Wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#SPEC_file_overview) site stating that:

> %changelog: Changes in the package. Use the format example above. **Do NOT put software's changelog at here. This changelog is for RPM itself.**

Have I been using the %changelog section incorrectly? Should it only contain information related to changes in sections such as %prep or %install instead of having change log information relate to the content it installs ([example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-find-out-linux-rpm-package-changelog.html))? I'm assuming the content can follow whatever guidelines the target RPM is for, but I'd rather confirm this assumption. The [man page](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html) doesn't appear to specify the type of content required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be (from the example on that wiki page) and a quick spot check of a few packages on my CentOS 5 system that it is for changes to the packaging which may mean changes to the underlying software (if the package was rebuilt to include an upstream patch to fix a bug or something) but doesn't include full upstream changelogs.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the changelog and the revision tag are both used to refer to updates to the specfile only.  For instance, if a new patch is applied, if the compiler flags change, or if the package is updated to build a newer version of the upstream source, then the revision and changelog should be updated to reflect those changes.  If the upstream source changes, e.g. to fix a bug or add a new feature, then only the upstream changelog should be updated.